# Why $P(\limsup A_n) = 1$ when $P(\cup A_n) = 1$?

Tags: probability

Let us have a sequence of independent sets like $\{A_n\}$, suppose for any $n$ belongs to $N$, we have $P(A_n)< 1$. If $P(\cup A_n) = 1$ why $P(A_n  \ \ i.o) = 1$?

Comment: A_n are independent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. If $A_n$'s form a partition of the sample space then $P (\cup A_n)=1$ but $A_n$'s cannot occur infinitely often because of disjointness.

Answer for the edited version: $\prod (1-P(A_n))=P(\cap A_n^{c}) =1-1=0$ and this implies $\sum \ln (1-P(A_n)=-\infty$. Since $\ln (1-x) \sim -x$ as $x \to 0$ this implies $\sum P(A_n) =\infty$. By Borel - Cantelli Lemma this implies $P(\lim \sup A_n)=1$.

Comment: Thanks, you say true, I have forgotten  to add A_n are independent

Comment: @Hamid I have proved the result under independence.